# Линейный градиент

Tags: html, css

Градиент рисует с не очень чётко, как можно сделать линию более плавной?

```css
div {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #fff 50%,#fff 50%, #FED700 50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[image: Пояснение]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте чуть размытие на край перехода, типо аналог анти-алиасинга.

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, transparent calc(50% - .75px), red calc(50% + .75px));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100px;
}
```